# How to integrate OpenSearch as a separate CatalogSearch engine to Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, search, catalogsearch

Does anyone know how I can setup and integrate [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/) engine as a separate Catalog Search engine to Magento 2.4?

I have removed all the ElasticSearch dependent modules from the `composer.json`.

From the OpenSearch engine, I have added [OpenSearch-PHP](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-php) lib to my project.

I would like to have OpenSearch across a website (Search page, Category pages) instead of ElasticSearch wherever ElasticSearch is serving its requests.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSearch is a fork of ElasticSearch and it's backward compatible with ElasticSearch 7.10.
So you can just point Magento on  OpenSearch and all will work as expected

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.htm